# I get just params of one field from form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have a `foreach` on some form and when I submit, i get all params of just the last field in my controller.

**form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple')?>" method="post" id="products_addtocart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $prod) : ?>
        <div class="border-new-cart-button">
             <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $productId ?>" />
             <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="<?php echo $prod->getName() ?>" />
             <input type="text" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>" name="qty" id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <button class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Validate') ?></span></button>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function addmultipleAction(){
    $params= array($this->getRequest()->getParams());
    var_dump($params);
    // Result:
      Array
           (
             [0] => Array
                         (
                           [productId] => 106
                           [productName] => shirt
                           [qty] => 6
                           [productTagName] =>
                         )

            )
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Now i get them like this:

[productId] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 106
                        [1] => 107
                        [2] => 108
                        [3] => 109
                    )

[qty] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 2
                    [3] => 1
                )


// I want to group the `id` and `qty` per product, something like this:
 array(
      [0] (
           [id] => 106
           [qty] => 4
          )

      [1] (
           [id] => 107
           [qty] => 3
          )
       ...
 )
```

Comment: I cannot find your fourth attribute 'productTagName' in the form whereas it is in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the inputs into an array like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $productId ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo $prod->getName() ?>" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>" id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
```

Note: the `name=""` attributes have been changed to have `[]` after them.

Comment: Look my Edit please

Comment: Sorry, there is no automatic way to do that. You could transform the $_POST array into an array that you like, but what you get is easily usable once you get the hang of it

Comment: Okey i will do that thank 's to all other users i accepted the faster one

Answer (score 0):

All of your inputs have the same name, so only the last one will be passed through.

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple')?>" method="post" id="products_addtocart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php for ($i=0, $length = count($_productCollection); $i < $length; $i++) : ?>
    <div class="border-new-cart-button">
         <input type="hidden" name="item[<?=$i?>][productId]" value="<?php echo $productId ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="item[<?=$i?>][productName]" value="<?php echo $_productCollection[$i]->getName() ?>" />
         <input type="text" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>" name="item[<?=$i?>][qty]" id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
<button class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Validate') ?></span></button>
```

I would do it like that to group the items together rather than having three arrays like the other answers suggest

Answer (score 0):

Add array in all inputs like

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/addmultiple')?>" method="post" id="products_addtocart_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $prod) : ?>
    <div class="border-new-cart-button">
         <input type="hidden" name="productId[]" value="<?php echo $productId ?>" />
         <input type="hidden" name="productName[]" value="<?php echo $prod->getName() ?>" />
         <input type="text" class="input-qty-product number-control" title="Qty" value="<?php echo /*$this->getProductDefaultQty() * */ 0 ?>" name="qty[]" id="qty-<?php echo $productId ?>"/>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<button class="btn add-to-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><?php echo $this->__('Validate') ?></span></button>
```

You will get what you want....